# Problem building proxy class for SOAP web service

Tags: .net, soap, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to build the proxy class for a web service using the wsdl
Executing this cmd

```
wsdl [http://WSDL_URL]
```

I'm getting

```
Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
R2706: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST use the value of "literal" for
the use attribute in all soapbind:body, soapbind:fault, soapbind:header 
and soapbind:headerfault elements.
...
Error: Cannot find definition for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/:BouBinding.  
Service Description with namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ is missing.
Parameter name: name
```

Is it something that I should fix on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might call it a "web service" it is apparent that it doesn't conform to the standard for the WS-I Basic Profile.

You will have to show the actual WSDL to determine what is wrong with it.

It's more than likely that it is either a non-conforming profile, or a different WS profile altogether.